# Authentication / account requirement for Tableau JS-API

Tags: jsapi, tableau-api

I am working on web application for visualization and learning feasibility of using JSAPI in application to pull in reports from tableau.

My understanding on topic is limited from online reads of dev doc and demo.
- Author creates reports, dashboards, workbooks on tableau desktop/server and publishes it on tableau server. 
- Tableau server will require a license for author personnel account.
- Web application can use JSAPI to access those reports, workbooks or dashboards.

Is my understanding correct?

Does does every user of web application needs separate credentials to view reports on app?

Comment: You can use a single account for accessing reports in your web application as long as you do not want to have some specific reports for particular users.

Comment: @Wojtek Thank you for input. Can multiple user access the report on server simultaneously? i.e User 1 & 2 using same Ui on web application to access different/same report?

Comment: Yes, we are currently using it that way and have not experienced any problems with simultaneous access of users using the same account and accessing the same report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a single account for accessing reports in your web application as long as you do not want to have some specific reports for particular users.